# Animated movie with fight scene in Big Ben

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I vaguely recall a movie from my childhood (so probably some time in the 80s or 90s). It was an animated movie (not anime) and it culminated with a fight inside Big Ben or another huge clock tower, among large gears and other mechanical objects. Unfortunately I remember little else about it.

Although this isn't much information, it seems specific enough that there are probably very few movies matching this criterion. Could anyone enlighten me as to what movie I am remembering?

Comment: Definitely not the answer to your question, but I feel "Cars 2" deserves an honourable mention. The secret-agent style jaunt in the Cars universe culminates in hour heroes suspended over the gears in a massive and very Big-Ben-Like clock tower.

Comment: @AJFaraday "hour heroes"? lol

Comment: @jpmc26 I actually didn’t mean to type that rather juicy pun.

Comment: @eshier This movie features a plot to replace the Queen of English mouse-dom with a robotic duplicate. Does that qualify it for sci-fi?

Comment: @approaching I haven't watched it in a long time (even though it is one of my favorite Disneys) & didn't recall the robot.  I stand corrected.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Lol. Yes, this is definitely on-topic.

Comment: To the people voting that this is not related to sci-fi or fantasy, the title is specifically listed under Wikipedia's [American animated fantasy films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:American_animated_fantasy_films) category.

Comment: [Meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11766/31394) about this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74538/discussion-between-forest-and-edlothiad).

Comment: I would suggest adding in your memory of the robots, even if it was vague at the time. This should help stem further close votes.

Comment: For users who are looking for similar stories in the future: see the list at TVTROPES WARNING http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClockTower in case any of them ring a bell.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Possibly Disney's [The Great Mouse Detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Mouse_Detective) (1986)? The movie ends with a fight inside Big Ben in which the villain's cloak gets caught between some gears.

> He then plummets to his death when the clock strikes 10:00 and shakes him off.

Also known as "The Adventures of the Great Mouse Detective" or "Basil the Great Mouse Detective" in some countries. It's an animal-based adaptation of Sherlock Holmes.

---

There is indeed a robot, specifically, a robotic duplicate of the Queen of English Mouse-dom:

[image: A royally dressed anthropomorphic mouse confronts her artificial duplicate, constructed in the manner of mechanical doll]

Comment: Yes that was exactly it! I seem to also remember that that movie is also where I first learned about rifling in forensic ballistics.

Comment: One of the great unsung Disney movies, and definitely one of my favorites.

Comment: I haven't thought about this movie in ages, but I probably watched it about a hundred times as a kid. What a classic!

Comment: A childhood favorite of mine as well!

Answer (score 13):

Honorable mention for the climactic clock-tower fight in [*Lupin the Third: Count of Cagliostro*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Castle_of_Cagliostro):

Comment: What's the site policy about "honorable mentions"? Your answer arrived after the other answer was accepted. I am genuinely asking, and I upvoted your answer since it fits with the OP.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to do them, since other people might search for similar terms for that other movie/book/etc.

Comment: @Taladris I believe they are generally encouraged for exactly the reason Florian mentioned.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: I agree with that. The (limited) drawback is that we can only accept one answer.

Comment: I remember this movie as a LaserDisc Video Arcade Game that I put many quarters in around 1985. Similar to "Space Ace" or "Dragon's Lair" LaserDisc Video Arcade Games.

Comment: @NJohnny That's right! They cut and scrambled the scene order if I recall... so playing all the way through ≠ watching the film. There was another laserdisk game around the same time... post apocalyptic, with a young black skateboarding/teleporting kid named "Sony"... can't remember the title.

Comment: The game was called Cliff Hanger. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhMheQKiFvM